# Mysql server configuration -- which file do I edit to change the tls_version?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change the value of `tls_version`.

I'm working through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html which contains the helpful paragraph:

> To change the value of tls_version, set it at server startup. For example, to permit connections that use the TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3 protocol, but prohibit connections that use the less-secure TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 protocols, use these lines in the server my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
tls_version=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

I've tried this, and the restart doesn't pick the change up.

I've also tried running `mysqld --validate-config` and it doesn't pick it up.

I have even tried inserting errors and I can't get it to fail.

What is the correct place to put this -- running version 8.0.3x . The docs can't be that wrong -- so if there is a way of telling which files it's reading in that would also be hugely helpful.